# Why would strace and /proc/pid/stat show a process taking no CPU time, despite the process doing work?

Tags: linux, process, proc

Have a long-lived process (couple months) that is handling a huge number of connections and doing work, yet most statistics on it show it doing zero work. Here's an strace output, showing a bunch of syscalls, yet 0 CPU time:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  0.00    0.000000           0     66376           write
  0.00    0.000000           0     27579           close
  0.00    0.000000           0        77           stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        46           socket
  0.00    0.000000           0        46           connect
  0.00    0.000000           0     21360       347 accept
  0.00    0.000000           0    140039           sendto
  0.00    0.000000           0    169718     21567 recvfrom
  0.00    0.000000           0     21013           getsockname
  0.00    0.000000           0     21013           getpeername
  0.00    0.000000           0     42026           setsockopt
  0.00    0.000000           0        46           getsockopt
  0.00    0.000000           0     63177           fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0     68858           gettimeofday
  0.00    0.000000           0      1861           clock_gettime
  0.00    0.000000           0       620           epoll_wait
  0.00    0.000000           0     96667           epoll_ctl
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                740522     21914 total
```

The `utime` and `stime` fields for this process are non-zero, but completely static, and not near of any int overflow limits that I recognize:

```
$ awk '{print "utime:" $14, "ctime:" $15}' /proc/128618/stat
utime:78891786 ctime:403631467
```

What's bizarre is I see this exact same symptom on several other boxes, with this same process. These are all running on kernel 3.13.0. This process is single-threaded, and not doing anything fancy (pgbouncer).

Why might a process continue to do work without having any of these statistics reflect that work occurring?

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a bug in the Linux kernel.

- Commit that fixes it: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9d7fb04276481c59610983362d8e023d262b58ca
- Discussion on the mailing list: https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/6/12/223

Comment: Is it possible, that kernel version is old enough...